# Quantlib Scehdule Error "Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Schedule'."

Tags: python, quantlib, quantlib-swig

Hi I am trying to create a quantlib schedule using the below parameters. I suspect the error is due to me passing a class rather than a class method?

I have bought the python cookbook and looked at Read the Docs for quantlib - is there another resource that has python code examples? There seems to be a huge variety of variables / classes and function calls and I can't see the wood for the trees!

any help much appreciated @Luigi Ballabio

```
import quantlib as ql

issue_date = ql.Date(30,3,2021)
maturity_date = ql.Date(23,4,2028)
frequency = ql.Semiannual
calendar = ql.UnitedKingdom
bus_day_convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing

schedule = ql.Schedule(
    issue_date,
    maturity_date,
    ql.Period(frequency),
    calendar,
    bus_day_convention, 
    bus_day_convention,  
    ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
    False
)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function

Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
[...]
Schedule::Schedule(Date const &,Date const &,Period const &,Calendar const &,BusinessDayConvention,BusinessDayConvention,DateGeneration::Rule,bool)
```

Update - I replaced frequency with ql.Period(frequency) as the function signature looks to expect a ql.Period object. The error persists.

Comment: That's a C++ error, not python. So this must be a bug in the library.

Comment: I am not so sure as there are similar questions with the same kind of error and the solution was  due to the calling signature and params being passed.For instance I noticed that the signature requires a period type for the frequency parameter and I have amended the code to have ql.period(frequency)  where frequency is.  The package wraps c++ so writing the error off to the library (which is widely used)  is not something I can do

Comment: You're right. I guess the library uses a FFI to call C/C++ functions, and it dynamically calls different functions depending on the argument types. So your arguments don't match any of these patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendars are classes, not enumerations.  You need

```
calendar = ql.UnitedKingdom()
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi - that was the issue along with neeeding to pass the frequency as a period. Quantlib is a great package - thank you - it is pretty intimidating though! Is there a way to get class and function signatures by code in python?

Comment: adding @Luigi to make sure you see

Comment: For classes, executing for instance `help(ql.UnitedKingdom)` gives some more information.